# How to use Flume's Kafka Channel without specifying a source

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I have an existing Kafka topic and a flume agent that reads from there and writes to HDFS. I want to reconfigure my flume agent so it will move away from the existing setup; a Kafka Source, file Channel to HDFS Sink, to use a Kafka Channel.

I read in the [cloudera documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_flume.html#concept_rsb_tyb_kv__section_mqc_tyb_kv) that it possible to achieve this by only using a Kafka Channel and HDFS sink (without a flume source).. (unless I have got the wrong end of the stick.) So I tried to create this configuration but it isn't working. It's not even starting the flume process on the box.

```
# Test
test.channels = kafka-channel
test.sinks = hdfs-sink

test.channels.kafka-channel.type = 
org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
test.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
test.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.topic = test
test.channels.kafka-channel.parseAsFlumeEvent = false

test.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = kafka-channel
test.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
test.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8082/data/test/
```

I'm using:

- HDP Quickstart VM 2.6.3
- Flume version 1.5.2
- The HDFS directory does exist
- `ps -ef | grep flume` only returns a process once I added a kafka-source, but this can't be right because doing this creates an infinite loop for any messages published onto the topic.

Is it possible to only use a Kafka Channel and HDFS Sink or do I need to use a kafka-source but change some other configurations that will prevent the infinite loop of messages?

`Kafka-source` ->  `kafka-channel` -> `HDFS Sink` - This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: What error do you have at the boot of flume ?

Comment: The flume process isn’t starting on the box, hence there aren’t any flume logs. Starting the flume service via Ambari doesn’t produce any error messages either.

Comment: You need to start the agent manually to find out which flume errors encounters at startup. <br />`$ bin/flume-ng agent -n $agent_name -c conf -f conf/flume-conf.properties.template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a bit I noticed that Ambari didn't create any flume conf files for the specified agent. Ambari seems to only create/update the flume config if I specify `test.sources = kafka-source`. Once I added this into the flume config (via ambari) the config was created on the box and the flume agent started successfully.

The final flume config looked like this:

```
test.sources=kafka-source
test.channels = kafka-channel
test.sinks = hdfs-sink

test.channels.kafka-channel.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
test.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
test.channels.kafka-channel.kafka.topic = test
test.channels.kafka-channel.parseAsFlumeEvent = false

test.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = kafka-channel
test.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
test.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs:///data/test
```

Notice I didn't set any of the properties on the source (this would cause the infinite loop issue i mentioned in my question), it just needs to be mentioned so Ambari creates the flume config and starts the agent.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question about Flume, but in general since you're already using Apache Kafka this pattern is best solved using Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka). 
There is a Kafka Connect HDFS connector which is simple to use, per [this guide here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart).

Comment: Thanks Robin, that is the strategic plan but for now I need this as a short term solution. I’m also curious to know how this is achieved.

Comment: The Confluent Connectors are not part of Kafka Connect, though. Your link assumes Confluent Kafka is available

Comment: It's also available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs)